# Multiline rule in beamer header using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, header-footer

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections,calc,decorations.pathreplacing,
decorations.markings}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=south west, yshift=-2pt, xshift=1pt] at (current page.south west)
{};
\draw[blue] ([yshift=-1cm, xshift=0.25cm]current page.north west)
  -- ([yshift=-1cm, xshift=\paperwidth - 0.25cm]current page.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A shor title}
  Foo
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A terribly long beamer slide title about some obscure meaningless
  topic}
  Bar
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

With this I get the following output:
[image]

So my question is: is it possible to use tikz (or any other package) to generate a rule that adapts to a multiline frame title? Thanks!

**Edit:** In my particular I need a solution that works also with uppercased frame title. Which I'm currently obtaining by adding the following line:

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter\insertframetitle}
```

Comment: You want the new rule be at the bottom of the second line? or the bottom of the first line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tikz` to draw a simple rule sounds a bit overkill - I would simply do the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{separation line}{bg=red}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,left,wd=\the\@tempdima]{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fteleft\endcsname\fi%
    \strut\MakeUppercase{\insertframetitle}\strut\par%
    {%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
      \fi
    }%
    \vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,wd=\the\@tempdima]{frametitle}
     \hrulefill\hspace*{0cm}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A shor title}
  Foo
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A terribly long beamer slide title about some obscure meaningless
  topic}
  Bar
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**TIKZ solution**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamercolor{separation line}{bg=red}

\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,wd=\the\@tempdima]{frametitle}
       \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[structure.fg] (0,0) -- (12.2,0);
       \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A shor title}
  Foo
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A terribly long beamer slide title about some obscure meaningless
  topic}
  Bar
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that I might also want to include an image in the header (that's why I'm using tikz). So basically this is not possible with tikz?

Comment: @petobens Is possible with tikz by not using absolute coordinates, but including an image does not need tikz

Comment: @petobens see my edit for a tikz solution, however I still think this is overkill.

Comment: If I add the following line : `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter\insertframetitle}` then your original code (without tikz) does not work. Can you please modify it so that i can also have uppercased frametitle? Thanks for the help

Comment: Also how can I add an arbitrary color to the rule?

Comment: @petobens Comments are not the place to ask new questions

Comment: I meant that your kind answer is not working in my real world example. In particular it is not working due to the line I mentioned above. I can edit my original question and include this line

Comment: @petobens You might get a better solution asking how to make the frametitle uppercase. I would suggest altering the origional definition of the frametitle template rather then overwriting it with  `\expandafter\MakeUppercase\ex‌​pandafter\insertfram‌​etitle`

Comment: @petobens I suggest to use a similar method as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356355/36296 for the uppercase, but this will have to be adapted to the theme you use.

Comment: I'm using the default theme. So basically there is no "simple" way of having both a rule and uppercase frametitle without modifying the frametitle definition?

Comment: @petobens see my edit